# Giving a geometric representation of Cartesian products

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is being asked of me?

Question 4 of Zorich(page 11) is exactly the following

> Give geometric representations of the following Cartesian products
>
> a) The  Product of two line segments (a rectangle).
>
> b) The product of two lines (a plane).
>
> c) The product of a line and a circle (an infinite cylindrical surface).
>
> d) The product of a line and a disk (an infinite solid cylinder)
>
> e) The product of two circles (a torus)
>
> f) The product of a circle and a disk(a solid torus).

i don't know what is being asked of me. I would have though the (a rectangle) would have been the answer to a), but the bracketed word is beside every one of the questions, which seems to be the answer

thank you(I don't actually know what to tag this sorry)

Comment: The question is not clear. Did you write the original question here completely?

Comment: @RoryDaulton that is the full version, but it seems to have what i think is the answer on each which makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the answer, but I believe you are being asked to give some geometric interpretation to them (you can draw all of those)